# How to make a variable return after exit in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, append

Okay so I have a program and it adds new entries to a structure to a .dat file. I know when appending it adds to the end of the list. This works fine. The problem I am having is that I have a tracking variable that keeps track of the length of the struct. I can bring back the items in the struct but how do I bring back the variable that is keeping track of the length. You can't find it's length either so I would have to bring back a variable. I was thinking leave the first line of the .dat file just for the tracking variable but I don't know if you can append just the first line.

Bellow is of course what I am using to add in items to my struct. Above it would be num ++ which means the length of the struct increased by one.

```
if ( pWrite != NULL ) {
    fprintf(pWrite, "%s %s %s\n", info2[nume].first, info2[nume].last, info2[nume].number);
    fclose(pWrite);
} else {
    perror("The following error occurred");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit program with error
}
```

Not sure if I am leaving anything out. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That is the reason why .zip files have their directory (that basically lists all files along with some metadata) at the very end of the file. To make it easy to add files to it without rewriting the whole archive.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes it has an array of structs. And the struct is global. I already have a variable tracking the array length. I'm asking how to bring that back after program exit,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements of the struct are of known length, then you can look at the file size and compute how many elements there must be. That is the easiest way to accomplish what you are asking.

**EDIT** After reading other attempted answers, and your comments, here is something that might work better for you - random file access. The following illustrates this:

```
FILE *fp;
int myCounter = -1;
fp = fopen("myFile.dat", "wb"); // want to write
fwrite(&myCounter, sizeof(int), 1, fp); // write size of -1 to start of file: "unknown count"
fprintf(fp, "Now I write something");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // point file to beginning
myCounter=1;
fwrite(&myCounter, sizeof(int), 1, fp); // write the new size: 1
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // back to the end of the file
fprintf(fp, "Here is something else");
... etc
```

It should be obvious how you can wrap this into a loop - note though that it would be slow to update the file counter on every write, since the disk will be "hunting" from one sector to another. So better write until you have no more to write, then update the counter at the start of the file with the `fseek` command. You do need to do the first write just to make sure you leave space. I chose to write `-1` as this would indicate to the reading program "no valid size has been written". Usually good to put some error checking like that in your code...

Comment: If the structs are being written out as shown in the code provided, this technique won't work: the STRUCT may be a fixed size, but its representation in the file is not (necessarily).

Comment: I thought bringing back my tracking variable would be easiest.

Comment: Did you see my later edit? I think it addresses your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Store an integer in the file which represents the amount of structs you have in the file.

```
[integer]xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

or

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[integer]
```

In the both cases, updating would require the `r+` flag when opening the file ([→ fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)). Then, you can simply read and then overwrite the integer.

```
// This may not work - my C skills got worse over the time :)

FILE *f = fopen("test.dat", "r+");
fread(buffer, sizeof(int), 1, f);

fseek(f, 0, SEEK_START); 

fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), 1, f);
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm looking for I think. I don't know anything about the r+ flag, I'll look it up.

Comment: This appends to the front of the .dat file. And doesn't overwrite the first line.

Comment: As written, your code will read the first integer from the start of the file (bytes 0 - 3), then write something into the next position in the file (bytes 4 - 7 if you have a 4 byte integer). I don't think that is what you wanted to do. You need a `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_START);` to go back to the beginning of the file before writing.

Comment: @Floris Thanks for the comment. The codes were actually meant as two code samples. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't saved the variable's value somehow/somewhere (for example, written to a file), and can't recompute it from what you HAVE saved, its gone.

Comment: I know that, I'm asking how to do that.

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file?  You seem to know how to do that.

Comment: Well I don't know how to write on top of just the first line in the file. I only know how to add to the file.